# Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

Title: Resolving TypeScript Error ts(2345) in Chrome Extension Development

I am developing a Chrome extension using TypeScript. I aim to retrieve all tabs, and utilizing the message passing feature, I intend to send messages to each tab. I have written the following code:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => {
  const data = {
    message: 'updated_channels',
    channel: request.channel,
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id!, data);
  }
});
```

However, I encountered the following error:

```
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'. ts(2345)
```

This error seems to suggest that the first argument of `sendMessage()` is expected to be of type `number`, but the type of `tabs[i].id` appears to be `number | undefined`, hence triggering the error.

I am utilizing the `@types/chrome` to supplement Chrome's types while working on this Chrome extension, so I presume the occurrence of `undefined` in `tabs[i].id` is unlikely. However, due to this error, I am currently using the `!` post-fix expression on `tabs[i].id` to disregard the `undefined` case as shown below:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id!, data);
}
```

Although this workaround functions, I will be writing similar code elsewhere, and I am interested in writing cleaner code. Please provide guidance on how to avoid this error.

On the GitHub references I am consulting, the code is written without using the `!` post-fix expression. Considering that my `tsconfig.json` configuration might be the issue, I attempted to mimic the `tsconfig` from those references, but to no avail. Please assist me.

`tsconfig`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["node", "chrome"]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

I change `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: It's a bug in `@chrome/types`. Switch to the [official chrome-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types).

Answer (score 0):

If what you said is true about the TS linter error coming from `tabs[i].id` possibly `undefined` (or even possibly not a `number`, then we can get rid of those possibilities and let TS know that what you have here is definitely `number` by properly handle the non-number scenarios.

For example, you could do

```
for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  if (typeof tabs[i].id !== 'number') {
    console.log('id is not a number! Disregard this iteration due to bad data')
    continue 
  }
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, data)
}
```

By checking whether the variable is a number or not essentially let TS know that you have done your part validating the type of the value you are passing in, so TS will happily deduce that the variable type must be a `number` and error will go away, and making things extra safe in case there's a value with unexpected types.

The `console.log` is completely optional, of course.